# How to test a component using Enzyme which loads based on Process.env variable

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, chai, enzyme

I have a DIV which loads based on Process.env variable could any one point me in a direction on how to test this section ?

```
{ process.env.STYLE === 'RNR' &&
            <div className="price-option">
            <span>$ <input type="text" ref="minInput" placeholder="Min" defaultValue={minValue} /></span>
            <span>{i18n.l('to ')} $ <input type="text" ref="maxInput" defaultValue={maxValue} placeholder="Max" /></span>
            <button onClick = {this.filterPrice.bind(this)} ref={(node) => { this.minMaxfilter = node }} >{i18n.l('Go')}</button>
            </div>
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach would consist of just setting the `process.env` variable to the value you want to test. Just remember to **revert back the variable to the original value** on teardown.

```
const originalSTYLE = process.env.STYLE;
process.env.STYLE = 'tested-value';

// your test

// Reset original value
process.env.STYLE = originalSTYLE;
```